# Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) formatting: No white space between generic extends and implements in Class declaration

Tags: java, formatting, eclipse-mars

I use eclipse 4.5 to create a class like this:

```
public class GenericTest extends ArrayList<String>implements Comparator<String> {
   ...
}
```

However, as you can see, the formatting is weird since there is no white space between the generic type `<String>` and the `implements` clause. This happens with both the Java Conventions formatter and the eclipse formatter (both default eclipse formatter). I cannot find an option in the formatting rules to override this behaviour. In previous versions of eclipse I have never experienced this problem (4.4, 4.3, 3.7).

How can I tell the formatter to insert a blank at this position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472205) that is fixed for 4.5.1